# Skip row value(s) with awk

Tags: awk, sum, row, sequential

I have the following input file:

```
 -0.805813  0.874753 -0.776101 -0.749147 -0.636834  0.379035 -0.004061 -0.004061
 -0.426119 -0.024801 -0.041989 -0.783686  0.361837  0.055206  0.368603  0.147965
 -0.632526 -0.100358  0.847947 -0.690233 -0.996141  0.445275  1.086014 -1.097968
  0.411383  0.411383 -0.734988  0.344954  2.577123 -0.372104 -0.923401  0.302907
  0.302907 -1.424862  1.165900 -0.776100 -0.776100 -0.495400  0.182533  0.002356
  0.002356  0.002356
```

I used awk to calculate the sum of these values in a sequential order (sum = -3.0000):

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum += $i } END { printf("%3.4f", sum) }' input.txt
```

Is there any possibility to use awk to skip values in a sequential order starting from the last line and to calculate sum for the rest of the values? For instance:

```
 -0.805813  0.874753 -0.776101 -0.749147 -0.636834  0.379035 -0.004061 -0.004061
 -0.426119 -0.024801 -0.041989 -0.783686  0.361837  0.055206  0.368603  0.147965
 -0.632526 -0.100358  0.847947 -0.690233 -0.996141  0.445275  1.086014 -1.097968
  0.411383  0.411383 -0.734988  0.344954  2.577123 -0.372104 -0.923401  0.302907
  0.302907 -1.424862  **1.165900 -0.776100 -0.776100 -0.495400  0.182533  0.002356
  0.002356  0.002356**
```

where I want to skip the values between the stars (sum = -2.3079). The number of values that should be skipped may variate.

Thanks!

I already achieved this by using sed piped with awk:

```
sed '$d' input.txt | awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum += $i } END { for (i=NF-5; i<=NF; i++) sum -= $i; print sum }'
```

However, a pure awk one-liner would be more preferred.

Comment: that sed/awk command doesn't ignore the values between asterisks

Comment: If your `sed` supports `-z` option, try: `sed -Ez "s/\*\*[^*]+\*\*//g" input.txt | awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum += $i } END { printf("%3.4f", sum) }'`.

Comment: please update the question with the expected result for the 2nd set of numbers where you ignore the last 8

Comment: You say "I want to skip the values between the **" but I assume your real input doesn't contain `**`s so what is it you REALLY want to do - skip the last 8 numbers from the input or something else?

Comment: @Nikola We're now seeing comments and answers posted here that assume you really DO have `**`s in your input that you want to ignore values between so please [edit] your question to clarify that aspect of your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripping down @markp-fuso's idea:

```
awk -v RS=' ' '
    NF {
        ndx = cnt++ % lastN
        sum += circlist[ndx]
        circlist[ndx] = +$0
    }
    END { printf "%3.4f", sum }
' lastN=8 input.txt
```

---

The reason his array initialization and comparisons are not needed is that awk [guarantees the values of uninitialized variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_03).

Splitting input on space (`RS=' '`) instead of newline and then checking the record has a field (the default behaviour of `FS` will split on the remaining whitespace), is more compact than his for loop to read each field, but requires that  there is at least one actual space character between each number.

Your example lines begin with a leading space; if they did not, my code would fail silently by discarding the first element on each line (it would become `$2` but `+$0` [is parsed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_02) as just the value of `$1`). If your awk supports using regex as RS (which a future standard may allow, and many popular versions already support), this problem can be fixed by using `RS='[[:space:]]+'`. (Or by using the original `for` loop to iterate over the fields.)

Answer (score 3):

General approach:

- to add all but the last N numbers ...
- as we read a number we place it in a circular list (aka an array with an index based on count-of-numbers modulo N)
- as we re-use a place in the circular list we add the previous number to the sum
- when done we'll have a circular list that contains the last N numbers and a sum of all numbers up to, but not including, those numbers in the circular list

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v lastN=HOW_MANY_TO_IGNORE '
BEGIN { for (i=0;i<lastN;i++) circlist[i]="X" }                    # initialize circular list
      { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            cnt++                                                  # increment count of numbers seen so far
            ndx=cnt%lastN                                          # calculate modulo index
            sum+=(circlist[ndx] != "X" ? circlist[ndx] : 0)        # add previous entry from circlist[] ?
            circlist[ndx]=$i                                       # add current value to circlist[]
        }
      }
END   { printf("%3.4f", sum) }
' input.txt
```

**NOTES:**

- assumes all inputs are valid numbers otherwise OP can add logic to validate the inputs
- assumes `lastN` is assigned a positive integer otherwise OP can add logic to validate the value of `lastN`

For OP's 2nd set of data we use `-v lastN=8` which generates:

```
-2.3079
```

---

To verify the result we can make note of the fact that the 1st number to be ignored (`1.165900`) only occurs once in the data set so we can hardcode this into OP's current code:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == 1.165900) exit; else sum += $i} END {printf("%3.4f", sum)}' input.txt
-2.3079
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming what you're asking to do is be able to skip the last N numbers from the input then using any awk:

```
$ awk -v n=8 '
    { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) vals[++c]=$i }
    END { for (i=1; i<=c-n; i++) sum+=vals[i]; printf "%3.4f", sum }
' file
-2.3079
```

or if you wanted to skip all values on the last line plus the 6 values at the end of the line before that:

```
$ awk -v n=6 '
    { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) vals[++c]=$i }
    END { for (i=1; i<=c-(n+NF); i++) sum+=vals[i]; printf "%3.4f", sum }
' file
-2.3079
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU AWK

```
$ awk -v RS='\\s' '!/^$/' file |
    awk -v n=8 '{sum[NR]=sum[NR-1]+$1} END{print sum[NR-n]}'
-2.3079
```

Comment: `awk 'NF{i++;sum[i]=sum[i-1]+$1} END{print sum[i-n]}' RS=' ' OFMT='%3.4f' n=8 file`

Comment: @jhnc: even better.. Was my first Idea!

Answer (score 0):

this `awk` approach makes no assumption(s) regarding

- #. of `** ... **` sections, if any
- whether lines end in `\r\n` or `\n`
- how many columns per line

The full input in processed in one shot, and bypasses the need for a temp storage array.

Even numbered fields, which would be where the skipped sections reside, get blanked out, then the leftovers are re-split into usable fields.

---

```
mawk 'BEGIN { FS =  (_ = "[*]")_
              RS = (__ = "") "^$" } END { 

   for (++_; _++ < NF; _++) $_ = __

        _*= FS = "[ \11-\15]+"
       $_ = $_
        _ = ++NF
          
   while(--_)__ += $_
    
   printf("%.16g\n", __) }'
```

---

```
-2.307901
```